# Cosa significa "esserci" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *La novella dell’apprendista esattore* di Beppe Fenoglio, in cui si narra la vicenda di un contadino, Davide Cora, che si asserraglia a casa sua, difendendosi a spari, quando vede arrivare l'esattore a riscuotere una tassa inevasa, ho letto:

> Giunse un soffio di vento, che diede nelle cime dei castagni e rianimò tutti, forse anche Davide Cora asserragliato nella sua bicocca. Ma cadde subito e si sentí chiaro nella strada sottana il rumore di una automobile e la frenata. Non potevano essere altri che i carabinieri, in grande anticipo, e l’esattore corse alla strada. Gli altri rimasero col fiato sospeso e Menemio mormorò: – **Ci sei**, Davide Cora, ora **ci sei**.

Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/essere1) ho visto che "esserci" vuol dire

> aver raggiunto lo scopo, riuscire in qualche cosa: *coraggio, che ci sei*; o arrivare a comprendere, a indovinare: *ora ci sono*.

Tuttavia, queste accezioni non sembrano avere molto senso nel passaggio sopra citato. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: qual è il significato dell'espressione "ci sei" in questo contesto?

Comment: Sul [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI05/GDLI_05_ocr_430.pdf) adesso ho trovato: «*Esserci*: essere arrivati; trovarsi in una con­dizione critica, in una situazione imbarazzante». Credo che sia questo ultimo significato quello meglio adatto al contesto del testo della domanda. Cerco di scriverlo come risposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi sembra che i significati che hai trovato nel Vocabolario Treccani siano utili a comprendere meglio la frase mormorata da Menemio. Si tratta di considerarli, diversamente dagli esempi proposti nel Vocabolario, in un senso “negativo”: Menemio intende dire che Davide Cora è arrivato alla “resa dei conti” con i carabinieri e l’esattore, non può più sfuggirgli.

Answer (score 2):

Sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI05/00000430.jpg) si può leggere:

> *Esserci*: essere arrivati; trovarsi in una con­dizione critica, in una situazione imbarazzante. 
>         *Pananti*, I-55:  Si  dettero  a  suonar  corni  e  trombette, 
>   /  a  dar  di  sproni  ed  a  schioccar  la  frusta,  /  dicendo:  Tu ci sei, qui non si scappa.  *Manzoni,  Pr.  Sp.*,  I (14): Quando 
>   si  trovò  di  fronte  dei  due  galantuomini,  disse  mental­mente:  Ci  siamo. *Marotta*,
>     I-241:  Ci  siamo,  Concetta, prepara i lumi e il braciere.

Questo ultimo significato è, secondo me, quello meglio adatto al contesto del testo della domanda. Cioè, in modo simile agli esempi di Pananti e Manzoni, Menemio vuol dire che, una volta arrivati i carabinieri, Davide Cora si trovava in una condizione critica.